# numfmt invalid suffix input

Tags: bash, cut, coreutils

I am using `numfmt` to convert a remote file's `Content-Length` from bytes to IEC format, i.e. `21M`

```
$ curl -sI http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.7.12/jruby-bin-1.7.12.tar.gz|grep Length|cut -d' ' -f2|numfmt --from=auto --to=iec
'numfmt: invalid suffix in input: '21981488
```

Stumped at why numfmt complaining about invalid suffix. When I split the command and check the output of `cut`, and manually echo the value to `numfmt`, it works as expected

```
$ curl -sI http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.7.12/jruby-bin-1.7.12.tar.gz|grep Length|cut -d' ' -f2 -
21981488
$ echo 21981488|gnumfmt --from=auto --to=iec
21M
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in coreutils-8.21 where we didn't quote the erroneous content correctly. If you run with the already released 8.22 it gives more obvious error:

```
numfmt: invalid suffix in input: ‘21981488\r’
```

Note if there are spaces or tabs after the number, then numfmt will ignore them (as it uses isblank()), but to ignore the \r would require using isspace().
Ignoring just blanks is correct I thnk.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the output from `curl` contains carriage returns and the *number* being passed to `numfmt` includes one.  You could remove that before passing to `numfmt`:

```
curl ... | awk -F: '/Length/{sub("\r", "", $2); print $2}' | numfmt ...
```

Moreover, note that `grep` and `cut` can usually be replaced with an alternate single command.